# URL Mapping File Format, PnP PowerShell, ConvertTo-PnPPage Cmdlet

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, publishing-page, migration

I can't find any references to the format of the Url Mapping File used with the ConvertTo-PnPPage cmdlet in PnP PowerShell. Can someone point me to a reference or provide an example?

Thanks!

Cmdlet ref page:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/convertto-pnppage?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple CSV file without header listing the source and target URL values. You can use either a comma (,) or semicolon (;) as delimiter in your CSV file.

Example:
https://contoso.com/intranet,https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/sites/hr,/sites/myhrportal

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages-urlmapping#custom-url-mapping

Hope this may help.